# How to ensure elements of a returned array aren't copied?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, complex-data-types

In the following code fragment (I'm experimenting with it to understand how modern C++ is different):

```
auto input(auto p) {
  std::cout << p << ' ';
  long long i;
  return
    std::cin >> i
    && std::set<int>{EOF, '\n'}.contains(std::cin.get())
    && i >= 0
    ? std::optional{i}
    : std::nullopt;
}

const auto input2() {
  auto a = input("Enter the first operand:");
  if (a) {
    auto b = input("Enter the second operand:");
    if (b) return std::optional{std::pair{a.value(), b.value()}};
  }
  return decltype(input2()){};
}

void reqNat() {
    std::cout << "Operands must be natural numbers!";
}

void binary(auto f, char op) {
  auto xy = input2();
  if (xy) {
    auto &[x, y] = xy.value();
    std::cout << std::format("{} {} {} = {}", x, op, y, f(x, y));
  }
  else reqNat(); 
}
```

are `x` and `y` subobjects of `xy`? If so, is the `const` in the return type of `input2` required to ensure it? What does the `const` change? Would it be good to put it on `input` too?

Comment: Or maybe the last line inside `input2` should be `return decltype((input2())){};` instead? [David Mazières' article](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/~dm/blog/decltype.html) seems to suggest that.

Comment: top level const in the return type is ignored

Comment: x and y are references to elements of pair (first and second), that is inside optional object  xy. So they are not "subobjects" of xy.

Comment: Whare is your array? And "are x and y subobjects of xy", no they are not they are [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) and if you capture by reference then they are that, just references. And you might want to read up on [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) too.
So if you have an array using std::array or std::vector and return that it is not copied.

Comment: @marcinj, I believed a subobject is an object (a C++ name for a value stored in memory, not necessarily an object in OOP terminology) stored within another object's storage. But  having reread the definition, I think the relation of being a subobject isn't transitive. So `xy.value()` returns a subobject of `xy` and `x` is a subobject thereof. Correct?

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike, thanks for this useful general observation!

Comment: @PepijnKramer, is the `&` in `auto &[x, y] = xy.value();` then responsible for ensuring copy elision? Or could it be dropped, just like the `const`?

Comment: No te copy elision takes place when the pair is returned (no copy of the pair is made) this is before the structured binding does its "job". `auto [x,y]` without the reference would then copy the pair, but `auto& [x,y]` will create two references to the pair's first and second member. (in essence just giving them a more readable name).

Comment: I meant that x,y are subobjects of a pair, not of xy. So - its not transitive in a meaning that if x,y are subobjects of pair, and pair is subobject of xy, then x,y is subobject of xy.

Comment: @NathanOliver-IsonStrike it's only ignored for fundamental types, not for class types. It's still pointless though.

Comment: I'll add this information which may be of interest: the standard mentions "direct subobjects" in the [definition of *transparently replaceable*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#def:transparently_replaceable), so it seems there could also be indirect ones and the relation is transitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> are `x` and `y` subobjects of `xy`?

Yes, in:

```cpp
auto &[x, y] = xy.value();
```

... `xy.value()` returns an lvalue reference to the object inside, and the reference on the left hand side binds to it. `x` and `y` are then going to be lvalues which name subobjects inside of `xy`.

> If so, is the `const` in the return type of `input2` required to ensure it?

No, and `const` has nothing to do with this. In:

```cpp
const auto input2() { /* ... */ }

// ...

auto xy = input2();

// note: this assertion would pass, because xy is not const
static_assert(!std::is_const_v<decltype(xy)>);
```

... the `const` is harmful, because we are declaring an object with `auto`, not `const auto`. This means we are unnecessarily calling the copy constructor of `std::optional<std::pair<...>>` to turn the returned `const` object into a non-`const` object.

In general, it is not recommended to put `const` on return types, because:

- for fundamental types, it's ignored
- for class types, it may force unnecessary copying

> What does the `const` change? Would it be good to put it on `input` too?

It only makes us call the copy constructor unnecessarily.
The following use of structured bindings works regardless of whether `input2()` returns a `const` or non-`const` type.

We should *not* put on `input`, we should remove `const` from `input2`.

### Stylistic Issues

Note that there are quite a few things in your code that aren't "good modern C++":

```cpp
// Constructing a std::set just to check if an int is one of two values is excessive.
std::set<int>{EOF, '\n'}.contains(std::cin.get())
// Consider using something more lightweight, like an IILE
[c = std::cin.get()] { return c == EOF || c == '\n' }()
// alternatively, make the set 'static const' at least


// Excessive use of deduced return types.
// The function name and parameters don't tell us anything about the return
// type being std::optional<long long>.
// Also, unnecessary use of function templates.
// You could have just accepted a std::string_view parameter.
auto input(auto p) { /* ... */ }


// If you have to do this, just use an explicit return type.
// This line is very surprising and could have been return std::nullopt; with
// an explicit type.
return decltype(input2()){};
```

Comment: That's a very complete answer, thanks!
Would you mind if I asked you further  in separate comments about some things it contains?

Comment: So, unlike @marcinj, and as I originally did, you interpret the relation of being a subobject as transitive?

Comment: The adage says cache invalidation and naming things are the hardest problems in computer science. Also, the DRY rule applies. Hence the `set`. Wouldn't the compiler optimize it, making the compiled code just as lightweight? If not (and even if yes, as a learning opportunity), how can it be made `static const` in an expression, without a variable?

Comment: @ByteEater to be entirely accurate: `x` and `y` are lvalues that name subobjects inside `xy.value()`, which refers to the `pair` inside of the `optional`. I don't see anything in the definition that disallows a transitive interpretation, i.e. considering `x` and `y` to be subobjects of the whole optional. See http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#def:subobject; however, the way that the term is typically used in the standard is non-transitive.

Comment: Definitely the `auto` specifier for `p` is overkill, turning the function definition into a template of which only one specialization is actually needed. Is `std::string_view` the best alternative? Not `std::string`? Is it the case that `std::string_view` guarantees no copying, but `std::string` requires it (though in this simple case I'd expect the compiler to be smart enough to optimize it away)?

Comment: @ByteEater `std::set` isn't lightweight, and it's difficult to optimize, because it performs heap allocations. It's actually a very expensive and complex container. It's unlikely that the compiler can fully optimize this. You cannot change the storage duration of a `set` in an expression, but you could use an IILE (immediately invoked lambda expression) and declare the `static const std::set` inside.

Comment: @ByteEater once again, I wouldn't rely on the compiler fully optimizing things away which involve heap allocations. `std::string_view` is a better alternative to `const std::string&`, and seeing that you're only doing `<< p` inside the function, a reference or view is enough.

Comment: OK, so one probably last two (related) things. Why `return std::nullopt;` isn't accepted when the return type (which is quite long, so seems to me like a good use case for `auto`: `std::optional<std::pair<long long, long long>>`) is specified as `auto`? And would `return decltype((input2())){};` (extra parentheses) be any different?

Comment: @ByteEater because for deduced return types, you cannot have conflicting deductions. `std::optional<T>` and `std::nullopt_t` are two separate types, and the compiler is unable to tell what the return type should deduce to. When the return type is given explicitly, then `return std::nullopt` converts to the returned optional type. And no, in this case adding more parentheses to `decltype` is meaningless, because `input2()` is a prvalue, so the type is the same as with no parentheses.